# iOS How to add many events to calendar by one loop

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, eventkit

I know that code below is very useful for create and add an event to iOS calendar. It work great and i can add many events, but with one event i have to make one touch on the button.

```
- (IBAction)add_event:(id)sender{     
    EKEventStore *eventStore=[[EKEventStore alloc] init];
    EKEvent *addEvent=[EKEvent eventWithEventStore:eventStore];
    addEvent.title=@"title";
    addEvent.startDate = [NSDate date];
    addEvent.endDate = [addEvent.startDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:600];
    [addEvent setCalendar:[eventStore defaultCalendarForNewEvents]];
    NSError *err;
    [eventStore saveEvent:addEvent span:EKSpanThisEvent error:&err];
    if (err == nil) {
        NSString* str = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@", addEvent.eventIdentifier];
        NSLog(@"Event ID: %@" , str );
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"Error %@",err);
    } 
}
```

Then i try to add many events with a while loop on the button touch event, my edited code here:

```
- (IBAction)add_event:(id)sender{
    int i = 0;
    while(i < 100){
        EKEventStore *eventStore=[[EKEventStore alloc] init];
        EKEvent *addEvent=[EKEvent eventWithEventStore:eventStore];
        addEvent.title=@"title";
        addEvent.startDate = [NSDate date];
        addEvent.endDate = [addEvent.startDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:600]; 
        [addEvent setCalendar:[eventStore defaultCalendarForNewEvents]]; 
        NSError *err;
        [eventStore saveEvent:addEvent span:EKSpanThisEvent error:&err];
        if (err == nil) {
            NSString* str = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@", addEvent.eventIdentifier];
            NSLog(@"Event ID %d: %@",i, str);
        }
        else {
            NSLog(@"Error %@",err);
        }
        i++;
    }
}
```

I want to add 100 events to calendar, but only 82 events add successful, all events from number 83 make some errors. Here is my log screen:

```
.......

2013-03-07 15:08:07.742 MyDTUSchedule[3066:c07] Event ID 79: BBCF7782-5D60-42D7-8478-EF80604FBF41:B0124DEE-EC5F-40B9-B9F8-312FA07D8059
2013-03-07 15:08:07.756 MyDTUSchedule[3066:c07] Event ID 80: BBCF7782-5D60-42D7-8478-EF80604FBF41:613F794D-67BE-4704-BEC2-7439E77965F0
2013-03-07 15:08:07.781 MyDTUSchedule[3066:c07] Event ID 81: BBCF7782-5D60-42D7-8478-EF80604FBF41:2FEF3B6D-6AC0-4058-AA79-BB46FEBDF732
2013-03-07 15:08:07.810 MyDTUSchedule[3066:c07] Error Error Domain=EKErrorDomain Code=1 "No calendar has been set." UserInfo=0x7e6a380 {NSLocalizedDescription=No calendar has been set.}
2013-03-07 15:08:07.812 MyDTUSchedule[3066:c07] Error Error Domain=EKErrorDomain Code=1 "No calendar has been set." UserInfo=0x7e6a9d0 {NSLocalizedDescription=No calendar has been set.}
2013-03-07 15:08:07.813 MyDTUSchedule[3066:c07] Error Error Domain=EKErrorDomain Code=1 "No calendar has been set." UserInfo=0x7e6c310 {NSLocalizedDescription=No calendar has been set.}
2013-03-07 15:08:07.815 MyDTUSchedule[3066:c07] Error Error Domain=EKErrorDomain Code=1 "No calendar has been set." UserInfo=0x7e6d5d0 {NSLocalizedDescription=No calendar has been set.}

...........
```

Would you please help me resolve this problem? I run this code in iOS Simulator 5.0. The iOS Simulator 6.0 make the same error but at event number 124

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be a memory issue. `eventStore` is allocated on each loop iteration and never released.

Try put `EKEventStore *eventStore=[[EKEventStore alloc] init];` out from the loop.

Comment: Thanks for your help. A few days a ago i tried to declare eventStore object outside my button touch event but not work. Now I do that again and it seem OK.

Comment: Everytime i launch the app for the first time, it does not work.. it works from subsequent launch of the app.. tried everything.. created strong EKEventStore property and compared with if(!self.eventSore){ self.eventStore = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];} in viewDidLoad.. what could be the solution?